# Verbial appropriateness for BUILDINGS

Tags: verbs

Below are verbs exemplified instead of 'build' for infrastructure(formal tone/register)

> 'Super dams' should be **erected** for the growing sea level.

Or

> 'Super dams' should be **installed** for the growing sea level.

P.s: Can these 2 *verbs* here be used? I'm a learner(that's why I am asking) but I doubt if the '**installed**' thing is appropriate. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can technically use both *erected* and *installed*, you should stick with *built* as it is far, far more common and easily understood.

> 'Super dams' should be *built* for the growing sea level.

*Erected* is on a huge downward usage trend, and it's usually used in very specific applications. These typically refer to processes that are literally bottom up, but also somewhat trivial to complete. You might hear that *"the construction workers erected additional scaffolding"*, but that's about it.

The word *installed* could work, but only in the most abstract sense. Typically, *installation* refers to placing something *prefabricated* (like a refrigerator or new windows) in a spot made for it. Not a brand new building or structure.

English doesn't require you to be ultra-formal, even in a professional setting. If you were to try to avoid saying *build* and *built* in an engineering document or context, people would think you're intentionally trying to sound superior -- not that you're being professional. Err on the side of simplicity and being common unless you're explicitly told otherwise.